# What are "Super Messages" with respect to Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I went through the documentation, but its very confusing. Can anyone help me understand this concept with respect to Marketing clouds. Especially, with perspective of Email sends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Super Messages are just another way for Salesforce to charge you more money. When you sign over your first born with Salesforce for the Marketing Cloud platform, it will have the number of Super Messages that contracted for. This [Super Messages PDF](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/marketing-cloud-super-message-bundles.pdf) shows how much each message can consume the number of Super Messages allotted in your contract. More on [Super Messages](https://ampscript.com/what-are-super-messages/)

> Any type of message sent to a customer including an email, a high
> priority email, a landing page impression, CloudPage impression, a
> Predictive Intelligence web or email impression, a push notification,
> or an SMS or MMS message. The number of Super Messages consumed per
> message varies by type of message.

Comment: Does anyone know if a Contact Update Activity uses a Super Message?

Comment: Contact Update in Journey Builder? No it does not.

Comment: Thanks @Jackson