# Super Message in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

In our contract a specific number of super messages is included. We want to monitor the number of super messages that have been used each weekly. Is there any way to do it?
Many Thanks.

Comment: For more details refer here = https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286053/what-are-super-messages-with-respect-to-marketing-cloud?rq=1